# Running many long cURL requests in the background with PHP causing Error 504

Tags: php, apache, curl, fastcgi

I am running an Ubuntu 16.04 VPS with Plesk, hosting with a few websites coded in PHP.

One of the websites has a function that does a POST request via cURL to another server (Lets call it Server #2).

When a user presses a button on the website running on Server #1, I need Server #1 to make a POST CURL request to Server #2.
Server #2 takes around 15-60 seconds to respond to the request.

To solve the issue of users waiting up to 60 seconds on my website, I moved the slow CURL request into a separate PHP file and called it with shell_exec.
This way the user on my website does not have to wait for the request to be completed. It runs in the background.

Here is the shell_exec function I am calling:

```php
shell_exec("php slow_request.php '".$parameter.”’ > /dev/null &");
```

=====

The problem starts to arise when there are multiple website users calling that same function at the same time. If there are <5 requests occurring at once, then my website starts giving a 504 Gateway Time-out error.

I also get the following output on my error_log.

Connection reset by peer: [client CLIENT_IP_HERE:****] AH01075: Error dispatching request to :
[client CLIENT_IP_HERE] AH01067: Failed to read FastCGI header

I have already tried the following solution from the Plesk documentation: 
https://support.plesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/115000064929-Website-on-Plesk-server-is-not-accessible-504-Gateway-Time-out-The-timeout-specified-has-expired-client-203-0-113-2-54693-AH01075-Error-dispatching-request-to

But this solution only seems to resolve requests that are taking over 60 seconds, not high numbers of concurrent requests.

How can I increase the number of requests that can run at the same time via shell_exec?

Or is there a better solution to running slow requests in the background than shell_exec? (I can't just make a request a set timeout to 1, because I need the response).

*Any help would be greatly appreciated.*

Comment: Can you show some code what you are doing around the `shell_exec()`? How are you giving the user (accessing server #1) the response from that async request to server #2?

Comment: It may be time to look into a queuing system, such as [RabbitMq](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-one-php.html).  See by having a queue with a set number of workers you can manage your resources better.  So if you get 1 million requests, nothing crashes it just may take some time to get to that millionth one.  AS it is now you would create 1 million background jobs.

Comment: It's also much easier to have your Web server publish messages, and maybe even multiple other servers consume them, horizontal like.  It's like a piece of wax paper between your brownies and your pan, or a separation layer that is loosely coupled.

Comment: @ArSeN The code around shell_exec() is a few PDO MySQL functions.    Also, the user doesn't need to see the response from the request, but it needs to be logged to a database.

Answer (score 0):

That sounds like you should have a look at [how queues work](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_queue)

Comment: I'm afraid that I can't use a queue because it's very important that the function runs as soon as the user requests it.